# I killed Kesh before starting “The Only Cure”—how can I continue the quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In *Skyrim* (PS4), I killed Kesh the Clean before starting "The Only Cure". I’ve got all of the ingredients needed for crafting the incense, but nothing allows me to activate or do anything.

I tried putting the items in Kesh's inventory, but it didn’t work. I also tried putting them on top of the Dwemer pot, but it didn’t work either.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the UESP entry for The Only Cure](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure),

> If you have accidentally killed Kesh before first talking to him, you can still begin the quest by **having the required items in your inventory and activating the Cauldron**. The potion will automatically mix and the quest will begin.